# Twilio - [Star] DTMF from JS client won't trigger conference hangup

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm having some hard times with twilio conference.

I connect from web browser using js client v1.3

```
conn = Twilio.Device.connect(params);
```

I want to create a new conference and allow this web user to hangup by pressing * and then add another person on the call by entering 10digits followed by #.
Here is python code that generates Twiml for this connect:

```
resp.dial(hangupOnStar=True).conference(conf_name, waitUrl='http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.soft-rock')
resp.say("Please enter 10 digit phone number followed by # to add someone to this call. "
resp.gather(action="example.com/add_participant/", numDigits=10, finishOnKey='#', timeout=30)
```

Here is a sample Twiml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Dial hangupOnStar="true"><Conference waitUrl="http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.soft-rock">room1</Conference></Dial><Say>Please enter 10 digit phone number followed by # to add someone to this call. Press any key followed by # if you want to be placed back to the call!</Say><Gather action="http://example.com/add_participant/room1/" finishOnKey="#" numDigits="10" timeout="30" /></Response>
```

After connection is opened, in web browser I try to send dtmf code for * that would execute SAY and GATHER verb.

For this I tried:

```
1. conn.sendDigits('*');
2. c = Twilio.Device.activeConnection();
   c.sendDigits('*');
```

But I connection does not hangup and thus it does not get me to SAY and GATHER verbs.

Same Twiml works good if I call in from a cell phone and send dtmf code from cell keypad. Users hangs up and SAY + GATHER flow follows as expected.

Also, if there is a second party connected to this conference, and I call sendDigits('*') I can here dtmf code on the other end of the call, it just won't trigger tha hangup.

Is there something about the JS client that I'm missing?

Thank you!